# use Regex to match from specific character count in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

My goal is to break up a string into groups of 44 characters with word bounds using regex in javascript. Because the total length will vary, I need the Regex to grab from the front of the string by character count. Checkout the Code...

```
highlight_whole = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dolor adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dolor adipiscing elit.'
highlight_1 = highlight_whole.match(/^.{0,44}\w+/)[0]
highlight_2 = highlight_whole.match(/^.{ //some code }\w+/)[0]
highlight_3 = highlight_whole.match(/^.{ //some code }\w+/)[0]

highlight_1 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dolor adipiscing"
highlight_2 = "elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum"
highlight_3 = "dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dolor adipiscing elit."
```

Thank You in advance.

EDIT: To specify my question, "//some code" needs to be replaced with code to grab from specific character count. What is that code?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I just updated my post to specify my question.

Comment: I'd recommend using capture groups `()` and grabbing the first match `[1]` in a replace statement so that you don't have to worry about omitting the first `n` characters of a string.

Comment: why not [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) or [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)?

Answer (score 0):

```
var highlight_whole = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dolor adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dolor adipiscing elit.'
highlight_1 = highlight_whole.match(/^.{0,44}\w+/)[0]
highlight_2 = highlight_whole.replace(/^.{0,44}\w+/, "")
highlight_2 = highlight_2.match(/^.{0,44}\w+/)[0]
highlight_3 = highlight_whole.replace(/^.{0,88}\w+/, "")
```

Here is a Regex solution to the issue. Let me say this problem is probably better solved with a for loop, however I wanted to post the regex solution for posterity. Thank you to those who commented.